# Why 32-bit windows supports near 4G ROM

Tags: operating-system

friend asked me a question about OS,in our computer,we can see it supports near 4G ROM if   it is a 32-bit windows,he asked about the ROM 4g is bit or Byte,i said is Byte of course,but now i can not find out why is byte

4 G = 2^32 Bytes

1 Bytes = 8 bit

4 G = 2^35 bit

so why 32-bit system supports near 4 G ROM ..

i am not good at OS ..

Comment: This question belongs on http://superuser.com/ not stackoverflow since it is about computers in general and not programming.

Comment: @papirtiger I have flagged it as such

Answer (score 0):

2^32 = 4294967296 bytes(B)

= 4194304 KB

= 4096 MB

= 4 GB

= 34359738368 bits(b)

And why ROM ? I think you mean RAM. ROM is like burned data on an external support (called as CD or DVD)
You can burn as much as data you want on a CD or DVD, depending on its size, but windows in 32 bits can only assign 4294967296 addresses. Windows is also using this memory space so you should have 20% (on 4Gb RAM) which is reserved for Windows to run.